# How to decide this Time complexity

Tags: algorithm, performance, time-complexity

```
for i <- 1 to N
   for j <- 1 to i
     for k <- 1 to 10
      print "x"
```

What is the time complexity of this one? n^2 or n^3? why ?

Comment: to get some intuition, you can try to count how many 'x' will be printed for different N

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the last loop for k goes every time from 1 to 10 which implies timecomplexity for last loop is `O(1)`. Hence now you just have to calculate TC for first two loops which is simply `O(n^2)`.